# What does $\text{VAC}$ mean in Weinberg's QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, vacuum

Hopefully Weinberg is sufficiently popular that this question isn't too localized. I'm reading Volume II (16.1, p. 63) and he refers to the state $\lvert\text{VAC}\rangle$ quite a lot. Does this mean the vacuum of the free theory or of the interacting one?

I think it means the vacuum of the free theory, from how he uses it. But I can't find the page where it's defined (and there's a lot of rather dense pages, so I'd rather not spend my whole afternoon trying to find the right line)!

Comment: From what I can remember $|VAC\rangle$ refers to the physical vacuum state. If memory serves, this should be explained (introduce) in the spontaneously broken global symmetries chapter.

Comment: There is a definition in $9.2.4$ Vol $1$